# how to mention a variable within a method in another class in javadoc?

Tags: java, javadoc

I want to mention my newDate variable in javadoc but I cant do it. Is there anyway to mention a variable within a method.

```
/**
     * Extends duration of a webToken {@link de.core.model.security.WebToken}.
     *
     * @param webToken to extend webtokens duration.
     */
    public void extendDuration(@NonNull WebToken webToken) {
        WebToken webtokenObj = getWebToken(webToken.getToken());
        LocalDateTime newDate = LocalDateTime.now().plusHours(WebToken.EXPIRE_ADJUSTER);
        webtokenObj.setExpireDate(newDate);
        em.merge(webtokenObj);
    }
```

Comment: IMHO, if the variable is internal to the function, it should not be mentioned in the Javadoc _at all_. If it needs explaining, add a line comment instead.

Comment: `newDate` is local to `extendDuration`. Even if possible, mentioning it in the JavaDoc makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry I want to mention it in another class.

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean with "mention" anyway? Certainly, you can mention it (even though it may not be good practice). Did you mean adding a `@link` to the variable instead or similar? If so, what exactly would be the expected behavior?

Comment: @MertYücel: As the others above have said: That's not good practice. The *implementation* of the function shouldn't be referenced by the JavaDoc of an entirely separate class. That's tightly-linking them (at the documentation level). If you really feel strongly about doing it, I doubt there's any JavaDoc construct supporting that poor practice and you'll just have to mention it in the text of the summary or description.

Comment: @tobias_k yes I mean `@link` `@see` or something like that

Comment: Your code is "broken" by design (architectural bad decisions) if you want to document one member field from a different class. The class you are documenting should not be aware of how it's cohort does it's job. Document the field on the class that owns it.

Comment: If you really want to put implementation-specific details into the javadoc, you could just wrap the variable into `<code>newDate</code>`, to have it formatted as code in the HTML.

Comment: Alternatively, you could create a function `makeNewDate()` and add Javadocs to that, then use it in place of `newDate` in the method and and link to that method in the Javadoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned, implementation details like the `newDate` variable should not be mentioned in the Javadoc at all -- not in the Javadoc of the method, and much less in the Javadoc of a different class. The Javadoc is for folks trying to *use* the method, and those usually don't need to know those things. What you *can* mention, of course, if the expiration adjustment, but there's no need to mention the variable or how exactly it's done.

Instead, if the variable itself needs explaining (for future developers, including yourself, wanting to change the method itself), add a line comment explaining what it does.

```
/**
 * Extends duration of a webToken {@link de.core.model.security.WebToken}.
 *
 * @param webToken to extend webtokens duration.
 */
public void extendDuration(@NonNull WebToken webToken) {
    WebToken webtokenObj = getWebToken(webToken.getToken());
    // the significance of the variable is ...
    LocalDateTime newDate = LocalDateTime.now().plusHours(WebToken.EXPIRE_ADJUSTER);
    webtokenObj.setExpireDate(newDate);
    em.merge(webtokenObj);
}
```

If you still want to mention the variable in the Javadoc, you could use `<code>newDate</code>` so it is rendered as code in the generated HTML documentation, or in the Javadoc tooltips of most IDEs, and also stands out in the Javadoc, but it will not link to the variable.

```
/**
 * Extends duration of a webToken {@link de.core.model.security.WebToken}.
 * 
 * The <code>newDate</code> variable defines ...
 *
 * @param webToken to extend webtokens duration.
 */
public void extendDuration(@NonNull WebToken webToken) {
    WebToken webtokenObj = getWebToken(webToken.getToken());
    LocalDateTime newDate = LocalDateTime.now().plusHours(WebToken.EXPIRE_ADJUSTER);
    webtokenObj.setExpireDate(newDate);
    em.merge(webtokenObj);
}
```

Alternatively, you could also create another method for creating the new date with the offset, add Javadocs to that method, and link to that method in the Javadoc of your original method.

```
/**
 * Extends duration of a webToken {@link de.core.model.security.WebToken}.
 * 
 * @see TheClass#createNewDate
 *
 * @param webToken to extend webtokens duration.
 */
public void extendDuration(@NonNull WebToken webToken) {
    WebToken webtokenObj = getWebToken(webToken.getToken());
    webtokenObj.setExpireDate(newDate);
    webtokenObj.setExpireDate(createNewDate());
    em.merge(webtokenObj);
}

/**
 * add useful Javadoc here
 */
public LocalDateTime createNewDate() {
    return LocalDateTime.now().plusHours(WebToken.EXPIRE_ADJUSTER);
}
```